# HSQLDB logging analysis explanation

Tags: sql, hsqldb

2017-02-24 14:58:05.929 2 COMMIT

2017-02-24 14:58:05.932 42 SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLES WHERE TRUE AND TABLE_SCHEM IS NULL AND TABLE_NAME LIKE XXX

I am using HSQLDB with hsqldb.sqllog=2 property, however during logs analysis I am not sure what are this "2" and "42" etc. numbers. Are they db session identifiers? 
I can not find any explanation. Any advices where to look for more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are session numbers.

You can find those SESSION_ID numbers together with more information about each session in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_SESSIONS system table.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation.